# Microsoft word reformat lines to take up entire line

Tags: microsoft-word

If I copy paste from a document into MS Word and previous document had a bunch of 'new lines' to format the text, which cause the text to be oddly formatted (lines skip to a new line without reaching the end of the line). Is there a quick way to reformat the the text in MS Word to get rid of non-needed new lines?

Version: MS Word 2007

Ex:

```
This question has many possible answers, and is the sort of open‐ended
question that interviewers occasionally ask. A good answer to this question might
include identifying the portion of the program in which the bug appears to be
occurring based on its behavior, as well as using breakpoints and a stepper to step
through the program. Any answers that involve thinking about possible sources of
the problem and finding ways to limit the search scope of the bug are good answers.
```

Comment: Do you have a small screenshot or example of text?

Comment: What version of Word?

Comment: Added example and version (Ms word 2007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quickly with Word's built-in find/replace tool.  In the find box, use `^p` to replace full carriage returns, and `^l` to find line breaks.  Be careful not to run them on the entire document or it will remove any legitimate breaks.

You can replace the `^p` or `^l` with nothing, effectively just deleting them, but I usually replace them with spaces.  Otherwise it will often run the last word of the upper line into the first word of the lower line after the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the creator of the content, as they are erroneously inserting line-breaks (e.g. `<br />`) into their content instead of letting the medium (browser, word, etc.) determine how to properly format the paragraph flow.

Since the content is coming pre-formatted with these line-breaks inserted in them, you need a way to paste the values sans-formatting, or remove the formatting altogether.

There are several solutions you can employ depending on your situation:

- You can use a word macro: [Microsoft.com](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/paste-text-without-the-formatting-into-a-word-document-HA001042961.aspx)
- You can use an online tool: [TextFixer.com](http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php)
- In [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/) use TextFX to clean up line-breaks (`TextFX --> TextFX Edit --> Unwrap Text`)